# My Girlfriend is Canadian and I'm American, we want marry, but she's not ready to live in th US

Tags: canada, immigration, marriage, illegal-immigration

My girlfriend and I want to get married. She's Canadian but with the option of dual citizenship, she would live in Canada for a few more months until we have everything sorted in the United States, but we don't know if she will legally be allowed to go back to Canada if we get married here. What are our options?

Comment: You're not asking for relationship advice, I assume. Don't ask what your options are, ask what the law says about doing X: what X are you asking about? Or, hire a lawyer to get legal advice.

Comment: What is her "option" of dual citizenship?  Almost every route to US citizenship is either automatic or requires living in the US for some years before being naturalized.  It's therefore rather likely if she has an "option" of dual citizenship that she is in fact already a US citizen, even if the US government is unaware of it.  Also, a Canadian citizen can't be refused entry into Canada by Canadian authorities, and the US won't stop her from leaving, so it's not clear why you think she might not be allowed to go back to Canada.